# Getting a DIV to go the entire length of the page regardless of length

Tags: html, css, height

I've been working on this for a while, I have done lots of searching here and have not been able to find a satisfactory answer, so I hope this is not a repeat question.

I have a wrapper tag which is designed to contain all the content on my page, then inside the wrapper there is a main tag which is about -60px from the top (making room for a header).  I'd like the wrapper and main to extend to the bottom of the page.  `height:100%;` Works fine for pages that are the size of the browser window but I am running into trouble when the pages are longer then the browser window, the wrapper and main run out where the window ends.  I have tried `bottom:0px;` `margin-bottom:px;` and I have no idea how to get this working!

```css
#wrapper {
 position:absolute;
 width: 990px;
 left:50%;
 height:100%;
 margin-left:-495px;
 margin-bottom:0px;
 
} 

#main { 
  position:relative;
 width: 990px;
 top: -60px;
 bottom: 0px;  
 }
```

I'm sorry if this is a repeat question (if that's the case please shoot me a link to the original).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try

```
#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    width: 990px;
    left:50%;
    min-height:100%;
    margin-left:-495px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

This way, the page will include the content past the screen height.